# How do I link one listview to another to create a football league table?

Tags: c#, listview, hyperlink

I am creating a football system in Windows forms C#. I have one listview where data is entered. I have 4 columns, 2 with team names linked to combo boxes and 2 with the scores linked to numericupdown controls. There are 3 buttons to add the results, Remove and clear. The code is below:

```
    private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(numericUpDown1.Value.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(numericUpDown2.Value.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void removeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem itemSelected in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
            listView1.Items.Remove(itemSelected);

        }
    }
```

I have another listview that I want to link the first one to. The second one is a usual English football league table and I want to use maths to add up the games played and the points etc. Please help.

Comment: How do you populate the comboboxes ? What are their data sources?

Answer (score 0):

How about working with events?

You throw an event everytime an item in the first Listview is modified, are an item is added/removed.

In the event handler you simple recalculate all the wanted values and place them in the second listview.